# Display a DIV across 2 frames

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, .net

```
------------------------------------------------
|      |                   
| frame 1                                       |
|      |                                        |
|      |                                        |
|      |                 frame 2                |
|      |                                        |
| - ------------|                               |
|      |        |                               |
|    MY Div     |                               |
|      |        |                               |
----------------------------------------------- |
```

What I have tried:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<frameset rows="0,*%" frameborder="0" border="0" bordercolor="#999999" framespacing="0">
<frame name="Top" src="./aspx/Main/Banner.aspx" scrolling="no" noresize="yes"></frame>
<frameset cols="20%,*" frameborder="1" border="3" bordercolor="#999999" framespacing="3" id="Bottom">
<frame name="TreeViewFrame" src="./aspx/Main/TreeViewPage.aspx" scrolling="auto" id="TreeViewFrame" />
<frame name="ContentFrame" src="./aspx/Main/ContentPage.aspx" id="ContentFrame" />
</frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

My problem is where should i place my div Either ContentFrame or TrewViewPage , How i get Overlay DIV Between two frames

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `container` as a parent then give `float` to both `iframe` and you should use `absolute` position for your `div`. note that container must be `position: relative`. if you need you can use `z-index` to order layer.

```css
body,html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#Container {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#mydiv {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: orange;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
iframe {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#iframe1 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

#iframe2 {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
<iframe id="iframe1">

</iframe>

<iframe id="iframe2">

</iframe>

<div id="mydiv">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Jiff Thanks for your answer , But my requirement is i want to open div  form either any one of frame ,

Comment: not clear to me this part `i want to open div form either any one of frame` , can you explain more? @Phanindrabaddula